# How to enable code coverage with Kotlin dsl gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, azure-devops, jacoco

When enabling jacoco with gradle kotlin dsl it fails because it looks at build.gradle file instead of build.gradle.kts file.

Here is the error :

```
##[warning]Unable to append code coverage data: Error: File or folder doesn't exist: /home/vsts/work/1/s/build.gradle
##[warning]Failed to enable code coverage: Unable to append code coverage data: Error: File or folder doesn't exist: /home/vsts/work/1/s/build.gradle
```

**app/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    jacoco
}

tasks.withType(JacocoReport::class.java).all {
    reports {
        xml.isEnabled = true
        xml.destination = File("$buildDir/reports/jacoco/report.xml")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.8.3"
        reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
    }
    finalizedBy("jacocoTestReport")
}
```

**Azure DevOps task**

```
- task: Gradle@2
  displayName: Gradle Build
  inputs:
      gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
      tasks: ':app:assembleDevDebug :networking:lintDebug :app:lintDevDebug --warning-mode all'
      publishJUnitResults: false
      testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
      codeCoverageToolOption: 'jaCoCo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages

```
##[warning]Unable to append code coverage data: Error: File or folder doesn't exist: /home/vsts/work/1/s/build.gradle
##[warning]Failed to enable code coverage: Unable to append code coverage data: Error: File or folder doesn't exist: /home/vsts/work/1/s/build.gradle
```

are produced by [AzureDevOps Gradle Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops) due to usage of option

```
codeCoverageToolOption: 'jaCoCo'
```

in your configuration of this task, because implementation of AzureDevOps Gradle Task contains hardcoded value `build.gradle`:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/9818b165441796437ca881c3f01bd7d90ee6856e/Tasks/GradleV2/gradletask.ts#L66
- https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9340

quoting [comment from the above bug ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9340#issuecomment-465776817)

> The way for you to use code coverage would be to enable it in your build config files and publish them using another task - [PublishCodeCoverageResults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Hey @Godin I have written `isTestCoverageEnabled = true` in my build.gradle.kts so is that enough you mean to say if yes then at which path will it generate the report.

Comment: The answer on question about path is in your configuration - you have `xml.destination = File("$buildDir/reports/jacoco/report.xml")` and `reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")`

Comment: Hey @Godin I have getting error `"Task 'jacocoRootReport' not found in root project"` when I build the solution is there any other file do I need to change.